# Could not find mapped image UITimerPicker*

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, storyboard

My compiler use to fail while trying to compile a code which contains a UITimerPicker in the storyboard.
Strangely this is happening just on the iOS5 simulator and device as well, but with iOS6 it is OK.

The result looks like:

2012-10-16 12:21:13.454 biztrip[7263:15203] Could not find mapped image UITimerPickerBackground-162.png

2012-10-16 12:21:13.489 biztrip[7263:15203] Could not find mapped image UITimerPickerFrameLeft-162-Bar.png

2012-10-16 12:21:13.490 biztrip[7263:15203] Could not find mapped image UITimerPickerFrameMiddle-162.png

2012-10-16 12:21:13.491 biztrip[7263:15203] Could not find mapped image UITimerPickerFrameRight-162-Bar.png

2012-10-16 12:21:13.506 biztrip[7263:15203] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: 'Could not instantiate class named NSLayoutConstraint'

The strangest think is when I don't use storyboard, but xib files all works just fine.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your issue: *'Could not instantiate class named NSLayoutConstraint'*. This means you are using auto-layout option. Auto-layout is iOS6 feature, that is why it's not working in iOS5 simulator.

Go to your storyboard, select ViewController (you'll have to do it for every ViewController) and uncheck *Use Autolayout* from *File Inspector* in the *Utilities* pane (pane on the right in Xcode).

Hope this helps.